# Executable exists for everything but bash & file manager

Tags: bash, executable

I am running Debian.

I was trying to use truecrypt the other day. I downloaded and extracted the zip, and ran the installer. I just extracted the file, and did not install it. I then tried executing it, and apparently it does not exist.

First I just double clicked the file from thunar (xfce4 file manager), and it told me the file did not exist. I then tried the following:

```
~$ cd /home/share/crypt/truecrypt/
/home/share/crypt/truecrypt$ ls -al truecrypt-linux_x86-64 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 abstruselyarcane root 4873328 Feb  7  2012 truecrypt-linux_x86-64 #Its not a figment of my imagination
/home/share/crypt/truecrypt$ file truecrypt-linux_x86-64 
truecrypt-linux_x86-64: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), stripped # It is indeed an executable
/home/share/crypt/truecrypt$ ./truecrypt-linux_x86-64 
bash: ./truecrypt-linux_x86-64: No such file or directory # It doesn't exist?
/home/share/crypt/truecrypt$ sudo ./truecrypt-linux_x86-64 
[sudo] password for abstruselyarcane: 
sudo: unable to execute ./truecrypt-linux_x86-64: No such file or directory
/home/share/crypt/truecrypt$ ldd truecrypt-linux_x86-64 
    not a dynamic executable # file just said it is an executable!
```

I am very confused right now.

EDIT:

I has been suggested to be that I'm running a 64bit from a 32bit, I went to the other post, and tested my distro:

```
~$ uname -m
x86_64
```

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to execute a 64-bit binary on a 32-bit system?

Comment: Check what version distro you are using: http://serverfault.com/questions/27590/how-do-i-know-if-i-am-running-32-or-64-bit-linux

Comment: The file is there (“No such file or directory” when you try to execute it is a lie — see the answer to the duplicate question). And it's executable, but not on your machine, presumably because you have a 32-bit installation but you downloaded a 64-bit binary.